# Keyframes Disappear

Tags: animation, keyframes

If I make a keyframe, some frames later move a bone then make an other LocRot keyframe, the previous one disappears. But if I step back there, the title of the frame turns orange. So it should be there, but the character doesn't move and the previous yellow lines clear out of the timeline. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you keyframe different objects? The timeline only shows the keyframes of the currently selected object, you might want to look into the action editor for more control.

Comment: I did. There's two objects, but they're assigned to the same armature. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. These screenshots helped me:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]